# how to echo print_r() array output

Tags: php, arrays

I got a bit probs how to echo `print_r()` output array.

```
Array ( 
    [one@gmail.com] => Array ( 
        [0] => 70,80 
        [1] => 90,100 
    ) 
    [two@gmail.com] => Array ( 
        [0] => 10 
    ) 
)
```

```php
function array_combines($arr1,$arr2) { 
   $out = array(); 
   foreach($arr1 as $key1 => $value1)    { 
    $out[$value1][] = $arr2[$key1]; 
   } 
   return $out;
} 
print_r(array_combines($a,$b));
```

I expecting echo:

```
key: one@gmail.com
value: 70,80 90,100

key: two@gmail.com
value: 10
```

Comment: Your expected is not array , it's json (object)

Comment: What are `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: Don't use `print_r()` if you want a custom output format.

Comment: $a = ['one@gmail.com', 'two@gmail.com', 'one@gmail.com'];

$b = ['70,80', '10', '90,100'];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop the array like shown below. The key is the email, then use `implode()` on the value

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: " , $key , PHP_EOL;
    echo "value: " , implode(' ',$value) , PHP_EOL , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-

```
key: one@gmail.com
value: 70,80 90,100

key: two@gmail.com
value: 10
```

Demo at:
https://3v4l.org/gXJcP  or https://3v4l.org/rN9LV

Answer (score 3):

First format your array to expected pattern using `array_walk()` and finally print using `implode()` the array by `</br>` or `PHP_EOL` glue. Example:

```
array_walk($arr, function (&$item, $key) { $item = "key: {$key}</br>value: " . implode(" ", $item); });

echo implode('</br></br>', $arr);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nLfKT)**